# Calculate proportions of point counts per polygon based on threshold values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, symbology, arcgis-10.3

I have an attribute table containing "Joint_Count" and Raster ID (A1, A2, etc), where Join_Count refers to the sum of points per raster ID.

If the sum of all Join_Count represents 100%, how do I retrieve the threshold values to represent 20% and 30% of all values?

```
FID   Shape    Join_Count        Y_Index     X_Index 
0     Polygon      0                   A           1
1     Polygon      1                   A           2
2     Polygon      2                   A           3
3     Polygon      3                   A           4
4     Polygon      4                   A           5
5     Polygon      5                   A           5
6     Polygon      6                   A           5
7     Polygon      7                   A           5
8     Polygon      8                   A           5
9     Polygon      9                   A           5
10    Polygon      10                  A           5
```

The sum of all Join_Count is 55, corresponding to 100%.

20% and 30% of all valus are:

```
55*0.2 = 11 and 55*0.3 = 16.5.
```

Next all Join_Count cells with a sum < 11 (<20%) should be coloured "green", sum values between 11 and 16 (20 - 30%) "yellow", > 16 (>30%) red.

In the above example, this corresponds to Join_Count values < 4 (<20%), between 4 and 5 (20 - 30%), and >5 (>30%).

Any suggestions how this can be done? I'm using ArcGIS 10.3.

I tried to add a new field and run cumsum(!Joint_Count!) in a first step, but I get an unknown error. Also searched through StackExchange, but couldn't find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

If i got you correctly, you need quantity based symbology. Here you can control over the class and classification method etc.See below for point data.

[image: demo]

========================================

Edit (as perceived by discussion)--
Try below field calculator python code

```
def classmaker(fieldname):
    if fieldname<=11:
        return 1
    elif 11<fieldname<=16:
        return 2
    else fieldname>16:
        return 3
```

and run the above prelogic code as

```
classmaker(Joint_Count)
```

on a field of which data type is short. Afterall classify by this code.

Comment: This was my first thought, but the probem is that 100% in that case is the max. Join_Count value (in above example = 10) and not the sum of all Join_Count values (=55). Thus, the percentages are calculated based on a wrong total value.

Comment: Have you tried quantile- go to classify then select method as quantile with 3 classes..I mean tertiles or terciles.

Comment: Yes, I tried it. The only solution so far is to calculate manually the thresholds and enter them based on 3 classes. But I'm sure there is an easier way of doing it. Maybe by adding another field in the table and calculating it there using the field calculator?

Comment: Oh sorry quantile will not do since interval is not equal..

Comment: have you update with this edited new code?

Comment: Thanks.This adds 3 classes based on the threshold values. But how do I get the threshold values (11 and 16) in the first place, if not calculating them manually? I.e. exporting data into an Excel table, sort Join_count from lowest to highest values and then sum all values to obtain 100% (=55). From the total sum, I calculate the 20% (55*0.2) and 30% (55*0.3). Next I have to search manually at which row the sum of all Join_Count is < 11. In above example it is the row FID 4 with Join_Count value=4 (Join_Count 0+1+2+3+4=10). Row FID 5 would already be >11 (Join_Count 0+1+2+3+4+5=15).

Comment: If your field is serialised then try http://www.maprantala.com/2014/02/13/arcmap-field-calculator-calculating-running-total-with-arcpy/